# How to get test to access ember-cli server when run in CI mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, ember.js, ember-cli

When running tests in browser by visiting `localhost:4200/tests`, tests are able to access the test server APIs.

However, when running tests in CI mode (using testem), they do not have access to the test server APIs.

Is there a way to make this happen?

---

Details

In a project generated using ember-cli, you can extend the server that it runs (NodeJs with Express). See instructions in `/server/index.js`. After running this command:

```
ember serve
```

... this server serves content on `localhost:4200`. I have done so, creating a server to respond to all the API requests, served at `localhost:4200/api`, when browsing through the app.

When I visit `localhost:4200/tests` the tests run in browser, they are able to access these APIs, and run without any problems.

However, when I kill the server, and run the tests in CI mode (testem), using this command:

```
ember test
```

... the ember app is run in headless mode using PhantomJs, but the app is not able to access the APIs, leading to most tests failing.

Even if I leave the server running when I start running the tests, the same thing happens.

I understand that it is convention to mock API requests within the tests themselves,
suing something like Sinon, or mockjax. 
However, that would duplicate what I already have in my test server, and I would like to avoid that.
Is there a way for the tests to run in CI mode (using testem),
and have access to my test server?

Comment: I don't think you want your http-mocks to be used for your test fixtures. I think the mocks are intended for you to use as you click around your app. Typically you'll need more control over the data on a test-by-test basis (think FactoryGirl).

Comment: you should check out [Pretender](https://github.com/trek/pretender) (and the [addon](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-pretender))

Comment: I disagree the http-mocks aren't useful for tests, I just have mine setup to ignore put/post requests silently so they original data isn't corrupted.  The fact that you have to run a second server is the only annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but depending on your project it might be a bit involved.

What you can do is running ember server in parallel to ember test. You then need to change the host setting of your ember data adapter and/or other AJAX calls (maybe make it configurable in environment.js).

The app itself is still served by the testem server though, and that makes the AJAX calls cross domain (as the port differs, even when both are accessed as localhost).

You then need to enable CORS on the server. There's a npm package `cors` that can be used as middleware in the express server.

In a simple case adding the CORS middleware will work out of the box, but if you use authentication or custom headers in your AJAX calls, more configuration on client and server side is needed. Read up on CORS in that case.

Here's how I did it.

In `app/adapters/application.js`:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: "api",
    host: Ember.ENV.serverURL || ""
});
```

In `server/index.js`:

```
var express    = require('express');
// ...
var cors       = require('cors');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(cors());
// ...
```

Comment: @ rainerfrey Thanks for our answer, and welcome to S/O. Your solution would mean, that it needs to start a different server, and run in conjunction with the test server. My motivation was to get it working together in a continuous integration environment, and thus getting the `ember test` command to run the server, just as the `ember serve` command does, would be ideal.

Comment: Well, AFAICT you can't avoid running the API stub server as a separate server, as testem serves the app code using its internal server, and you can't add a dynamic application to that. It should be possible though to have ember test (or maybe a custom ember command) start the server. I have this working with the grunt based Ember App Kit, but haven't found an obvious way to to this with ember-cli as I don't know broccoli nor how to extend ember-cli. Even then, what I wrote about CORS and configuring the REST adapter still applies.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but it may solve your problem.  In travis-ci I start an ember server and then point tests at it.
https://github.com/ilios/frontend/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: How is that server stopped after the tests finish?

Comment: Travis kills the VM so it dies then.  You could kill the job instead kill %1 should work in this case.

Comment: I just tried this: set up new host parameters for localhost:4200 as you say, and then ran `ember server` in one instance and `ember test` in another. It worked the first time, but whenever I keep running it again, it no longer tries to connect to the hosts and reverts back to trying to connect to the default port. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by this issue for ember-cli: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/1763; there's a PR pending to fix it: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/2969

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage. It uses pretender internally, can be used for both the app and tests simultaneously with same data.

We recently switched from **http-mocks + Pretender** combo to `ember-cli-mirage` and it looks quite promising.

Comment: There are certain things that can't do done through mirage at the moment, such as middleware. Only an express server instance can provide that.